# How to write a REPL for browser?

Tags: javascript, shell, read-eval-print-loop, elixir

I'd like to make a browser based REPL for Elixir, similar to joshnuss.github.io/mruby-web-irb for Ruby, or tour.golang.org/welcome/1 for Go.

I'm wondering what different implementations of browser based REPL's might look like - for example, is having the REPL just be essentially a JS input box whose value is sent to my server (perhaps using websockets) to be computed by the Elixir runtime viable?

I suppose I'd have to disable many commands, such as those that interact with the file system. Is that a real option, or is there a better way to implement a web based REPL that I haven't thought of?

Comment: There is at least one project that does this already.  https://github.com/stevedomin/ex_playground

Comment: 1.) As @FredtheMagicWonderDog points out there is already a browser REPL for Elixir (actually there's another one he didn't mention too). 2.) Even if there were a need to create one, your question is a bit broad and general. Vote to close.

Comment: // , Leo, this is definitely something that people can use to learn Elixir. Is there some way to make this question more specific?